# Create a div with text inside image. (responsive design)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to create a div which contains an image and text on it. Something similar to http://wearyoubelong.com/ How do I go about doing this? I am using Zerb Foundation Framework. As of now I have tried using position : absolute on the text, but that seems to break at a lot of places. Can you please advice me on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have a sample HTML like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <h1>Here goes some content</h1>
    <p>Description about the product.
    Some more desription about the product.</p>
</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    background-image:url('http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00cZjaqNvWlEks/Men-T-Shirt.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}

#content
{
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    top:150px;
    left:100px;
}
#content h1
{
   color:Yellow;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:22px;
}

#content p
{
    color:Red;
}
```

Just gave the main `div` `#container` a `background-image` , positioned `div` `#content` to `absolute` and then using `top` and `left` property float it according to your needs.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duhhz/1/)**

Hope this helps.

**Edited to set #container div's height and width to auto**

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duhhz/2/)**
    ​

Comment: If I set height and width in px, won't it affect the responsive design?

Comment: @parjun Do you want that the #container div should have height and width auto?

Comment: Yes. I tried this but it wasnt working as expected. The image becomes too small at high resolutions and the text overflows.

Comment: @parjun For background image to work properly you have to set height and width of the div accoding to your images.

Comment: Yes. But how do I go about with it in a responsive design?

Comment: @parjun You mean that the demo should work with height and width to auto right?

Comment: @parjun If you want the height and width auto then you might have to use `<img/>` tag.See my edited demo.